# Detect when user leaves outlet

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have the following route configuration:

```
{
    path: 'foo',
    component: 'fooComponent'
},
{
    path: 'bar',
    children: [
        {
            path: ':barId',
            component: barComponent,
            children: [
                {
                    path: ':bazId',                
                    component: bazComponent,
                    outlet: 'baz'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm currently on `bazComponent`. The current URL is `http://localhost:4200/bar/barId/(baz:bazId)`

Is there any way to detect when the user has left `bazComponent`?

I need to execute some code when the user navigates from `bazComponent` to any other route that does not contain the `baz` outlet.

EDIT:
The code I have to execute is within function inside the component that can't be moved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably create an Angular [Route Guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) and use the [`CanDeactivate`](https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate) to execute the code that you want to be executed on leaving that route, this is preferable if you need to apply to multiple routes.

After you mentioned that it needs to call a function within that component and it's just for the single component you should use [OnDestroy](https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy).

```
class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
  ngOnDestroy() {
    // Call to function/method here.
  }
}
```

Check out the [Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

Answer (score 0):

Is onDestroy enough for your usecase?

@see https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy